# Magnific Popup: Is Ajax content indexed by Google? (SEO)

Tags: ajax, responsive-design, seo, lightbox, magnific-popup

I'm planning to modernize the photo gallery on my website. Currently I use the Colorbox plugin to open the large image and legend in a lightbox after clicking on a thumbnail. Google indexes the pictures and legends yet optimal.

My new photo gallery should be responsive and I want to show not only the photo and legend inside of the lightbox, but also further information like date, location, camera, tags, etc. That's why I will use the Ajax option rather than the standard gallery option of the lightbox plugin.

The thumbnails are compiled dynamically based on filtering and sorting settings and the information about the photos is stored in a database. So I will use a PHP script to get the necessary information and to set up the HTML code for the Ajax call dynamically. That should be no problem.

My question is: Will the contents that is loaded via Ajax in the Magnific Popup be indexed by Google?
Unfortunately I do not think so, because if I make a Google search for a part of the text which is displayed in the Ajax Lightbox on http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/, this page does not appear in the Google results...

Is there a solution? Or can you recommend another responsive Lightbox wherein the Ajax content will be indexed?

Thank you for any suggestion!
Michelle